# How to use two (or more) webcams on Skype?

Tags: skype, webcam

How to use two (or more) webcams on Skype?

I give music lessons, and it would be great if the student could see my face and what I do with my hands on the instrument at the same time.

I've tried OBS, but they were delays.
I've searched other solutions,but haven't found any.

Comment: OBS may be the only way. I don't think Skype natively supports two (or more) webcams.

Comment: @user68186 is correct, Skype doesn’t support that itself. I’d suggest OBS, although there are some settings to artificially make a delay in the output, so make sure that is off

Comment: I heard that skype's screen sharing works on wayland. so that means you can use pipewire to route your cameras to skype. [Pipewire routing example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoC0r.png) [Installing Pipewire](https://wiki.debian.org/PipeWire#Installation)

Comment: A mirror? Like, a physical piece of reflective glass; could that work for you?

Comment: @pbhj Oh, I've never thought about that. That's what is called thinking out of the box!! (and yet so simple)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the powerful tool, FFMPEG, and a "fake" camera [v4l2loopback](https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback).
Install `ffmpeg` and `v4l2loopback` first.
Then, check your existing video devices:

```
ls /dev/video*
```

Note the outputs. Now do:

```
sudo modprobe v4l2loopback devices=1 card_label="Very Real HD Webcam" exclusive_caps=1
```

This creates a video device.

Then use:

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video0 -i /dev/video1 \
-filter_complex "[1:v]scale=500:-1[v2];[0:v][v2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5" \
-c:a copy -pix_fmt rgb24 -vsync 2 -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

/dev/video0 and /dev/video1 are your real webcams. /dev/video2 is the device created by v4l2loopback. Change if necessary with outputs from the first `ls` command.

You can test the video with

```
ffplay /dev/video2
```

There will still be some delays, but it should not be much of an issue. If there is a delay on only one of the cams (out of sync), there might be a framerate issue, which is what happened to me. Add `-r`  to specify input framerate (fps). You can find it out with `ffprobe /dev/video0` for example.

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -i /dev/video0 -r 10 -i /dev/video1 \
-filter_complex "[1:v]scale=500:-1[v2];[0:v][v2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5" \
-c:a copy -pix_fmt rgb24 -vsync 2 -f v4l2 /dev/video2
```

Ffmpeg filter code taken from: https://superuser.com/a/1721227.
I'm not very good with ffmpeg filters, but you can do some googling to change it if you need. This one puts second cam to top right corner

Comment: It's good, but there is some delays between both images. Even though I've tried both, and have searched on internet, it still has a lot of delay - which makes the answer unusable. (for information, I use 2 pretty good webcams, same models: logitechs C922 pro stream ; 640/480 ; 30 fps)